# php documentation tags in git

Tags: php, git, documentation, github

is there a way to automatically get git/github to update the doc tags in a PHP document to reflect the current version/tag? Something like

```
/**
 * @version {tag} - {date}
 * @package My Product
 * @copyright (C) 2011 Me Inc.
 * @license see mylicense.txt
 */
```

If I go in and manually do a find/replace for these tags then it messes up the commit history, since every file looks like it was altered when it was simply a version change.

Thanks

Comment: The git system will have to modify the file as well, so no matter what it will look like it was altered even though it was a version change. That said I am sure there is a way, but thought I would just point that out.

Comment: Hi Brad-- I was thinking that *if* this could work as I'm imagining, the vars {tag} and {data} would just stay as they are, and would only get interpreted when an archive is downloaded.

Comment: Why would you change the version if the file hasn't changed? :)

Comment: hi magnus-- because the version in the file will correspond to the git tag (eg. I tag the current state of code at v 2.0, and this will create a 'view' of the code at that tag-- even though some files were not modified from the v 1.0 release, they still belong in the v2.0 product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to tag after you change the code comment. Git bases the ids of commits based upon the contents of them. It's better for build artifacts to contain version references. You can also take a look at smudge/clean scripts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @adymitruk-- thanks for the info, can you explain how to use artifacts or what they are? thanks!

Comment: sure. Once you have your official release, rely on something like `export TAG_NAME=v2.2.0 && git tag TAG_NAME && git push --tags && git export | tar xvzf /some/path/$TAG_NAME && echo release $TAG_NAME >> /some/path/releasenotes.txt && tar a /some/path .`